# JHipster: how customize domain classes generated by EntityServerGenerator

Tags: jhipster, blueprint

I'm trying to make a simple change in the domain classes generated by JHipster 7.9.3, I just want to change the sequenceGenerator name:

```
 get [POST_WRITING_ENTITIES_PRIORITY]() {
        this.log(`[DEBUG] POST_WRITING_ENTITIES_PRIORITY: get`);
        return {
            async postWritingTemplateTask() { 
              const asEntityClass = this.asEntity(this.entity.name);
              this.editFile( `${SERVER_MAIN_SRC_DIR}${this.jhipsterConfig.packageFolder}/domain/${asEntityClass}.java`, content => {
                return content.replaceAll(' = "sequenceGenerator"', ` = "seq${asEntityClass}"`);
              });
            },
        };
    }
```

The problem is that the "get" function is never called.

When I tried to use the priority POST_WRITING_PRIORITY, the content of entity classes don't have the content still processed, the content is something like the following:

```
@Schema(description = "not an ignored comment")
<&- fragments.annotationSection() -&>
@SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")
public class MyEntity <&- fragments.extendsSection() -&>implements Serializable<&- fragments.additionalInterfacesSection() -&> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Finally, I tried to use the `END_PRIORITY`. It kind of works, but it always asks for confirmation to overwrite the files.

Is there a better way to customize the domain classes generated by JHipster?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I've found out my mistake! I was inheriting my generator from the wrong class:

```
import EntityServerGenerator from 'generator-jhipster/esm/generators/entity-server';
...
export default class extends EntityServerGenerator {
 ...
}
```

After the following change, the problem was partially solved. Now, the "get" function is called and the functions returned by it are called also.

```
import { GeneratorBaseEntities } from 'generator-jhipster';
...
export default class extends GeneratorBaseEntities {
 ...
}
```

However, the content of entities classes still have those "fragments" notation:

```
@Schema(description = "not an ignored comment")
<&- fragments.annotationSection() -&>@SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")
public class MyEntity <&- fragments.extendsSection() -&>implements Serializable<&- fragments.additionalInterfacesSection() -&> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```